# Jenkins command to display all file in directory?

Tags: java, python, grails, jenkins

I have created a workspace and clone all files in to that. Now, I'm running my code through jenkins. Can anyone assist how to display all the files in my workspace through any command. I tried with `${workspace} dir` in Jenkins but it is showing any output.

Basically, if you are at any folder in your system and you open cmd and exceute `dir` in windows, it will display all the files in it. 
The same thing I want to see in Jenkins for windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `dir` in jenkins (in a batch task).

Comment: @tkausl Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `dir` no `${workspace}`

`bat 'dir'` in a pipeline script.

Select a "**execute batch command**" option and write the commands you want to execute in there.

Then check the console output of the build which was successful.